# Creating a file in Java with a dynamic name, getting syntax is incorrect error

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm writing a simple Java app which basically logs the output of a serial device (kinda like PuttY). so far the streaming and displaying of data is working, I am moving into the file creation and writing part of the program and I was testing out some code i read about creating a file:

```
public void createNewFile() {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss");
    String newFileName = dateFormat.format(System.currentTimeMillis());
    try {
        File newFile = new File("C:\\Boxtest-%s.txt",newFileName);
        boolean fvar = newFile.createNewFile();
        if (fvar) {
            System.out.println("File created successfully");
            updateStatus("File created successfully!");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("File already present");
            updateStatus("File already exists");
        }
        
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception!");
        updateStatus(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    
}
```

When I look at my status for the error message I get the error "The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect".
I assume this is due to the name of the file having a variable? ("C:\Boxtest-%s", newFileName) but then how can I make it create a new file every time I start the button and use the current date/time in the file name to avoid overwriting older files?

Comment: Some OSs don't allow colons (`:`) in file names.

Comment: What do you believe `new File("C:\\Boxtest-%s.txt",newFileName)` does, and why do you believe that? *Hint:* It does **not** substitute `%s` with the value of `newFileName`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem are the colons in your date format. They are not allowed for filenames in Windows.

You can use System.currentTimeMillis(); without the format or a format  without colons.

Comment: Thank you. You are correct. However, now that I replaced the format with underscores (_) instead of colons, I am getting the error: "The system cannot find the path specified"

Comment: The string replacement does not work here. Try something like

String newFileName = "C:\\Boxtest-" + dateFormat.format(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".txt";
        
try {
            File newFile = new File(newFileName);
...

Comment: You probably will get a "access denied" error next. You can change to the "C:\temp\" directory to work around that.

Comment: Thank you Kornejew, that worked. I updated a new answer with the code that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so as it was suggested the fix to this was the following:

- Removing colons from filenames as OS does not permit it.
- New code snippet below:

  fullFilePath = String.format("C:\boxtest\%s-Boxtest.txt", newFileName);
  File newFile = new File(fullFilePath);

So apparently %s is not replaced by newFileName in the New File callout, so I had to do it using a format string and then use the full path in the New File callout.
This is now owrking .Thank you Kornejew